# Правильно ли стоят запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Проезд в Севастополе подорожает, но когда, неизвестно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Проезд в Севастополе подорожает, но когда, неизвестно.*

Лучше поставить тире:

***Проезд в Севастополе подорожает, но когда —  неизвестно.***

.

См. [**у Розенталя:**](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_38.htm)

> **§ 38**. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении
>
> 1. Тире ставится для интонационного отделения главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего тире
>      употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует:
>
> 1) придаточная изъяснительная: *Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак
>   не мог он понять (Г.); Как рассказывал учитель — долго слушал у окна я
>   (Пл.); Конечно, хорошо, что он с ней венчается, а как жить будут — кто
>   знает (М. Г.); За что он её мучил — она так и не спросила; **Он
>   придёт, но когда — не знаю*** (ср. при другом порядке частей: *Не
>   знаю, когда он придёт*).

Answer (score 2):

- Проезд в чем: в метро, в маршрутках, в автобусах? Или вообще проезд в общественном транспорте?
- После "когда" лучше поставить тире.

**Проезд в общественном транспорте в Севастополе подорожает, но когда — неизвестно.**

Answer (score 1):

Лучше поставить тире: *Проезд в Севастополе подорожает, но когда -- неизвестно*.